# mysql query to get just the 1st sentence in a paragraph

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to copy over just the 1st sentence in a description paragraph of a product for a meta-description tag in a mysql database.  For instance. in this product description, i just need the 1st sentence to copy over from the products_description field to the products_meta_description field.

"The Kendall Howard 8U Compact Series SOHO Server Cabinet Rack is ideal for IT setups with limited space. The sleek, durable design is specifically constructed for small businesses, home offices, or IT professionals who want a compact design without sacrificing the safety of their server rack equipment."

should be copied to products_meta_description as:
"The Kendall Howard 8U Compact Series SOHO Server Cabinet Rack is ideal for IT setups with limited space."

```
UPDATE products SET products_meta_description = products_description(1st sentence only)
```

not sure how to do that.  I'm assuming it would have find the 1st period (.) found in the paragraph and just get everything before that.  btw, i'm doing this in phpmyadmin sql query tool.  there are thousands of products so I thought this would be the easiest way to get a canned meta description tag entered for each product vs. doing it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function is ideal for this:

```
UPDATE products
SET products_meta_description = SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_description, '.', 1)
```

That will give you everything that comes *before* the first period. If you want the period as well, it's easiest to just `CONCAT` it to the result:

```
UPDATE products
SET products_meta_description = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_description, '.', 1), '.')
```

Comment: This may be a MySQL version thing; I'm running on 5.1 where `SUBSTRING_INDEX` requires three arguments, the third being a count. If you have this problem, you'll need to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_description, '.', 1)`

Comment: No, it's a "me forgetting the third parameter" thing :) Thanks for the catch! I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's function `SUBSTRING_INDEX` should help you:

```
UPDATE products SET products_meta_description = SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_description, '.', 1)
```

This query should update "products_meta_description" field using text coming from "products_description" field till the first occurrence of a '.'

Full stop is not included so if you need it you must add it by concatenating strings (first argument is an empty separator).

```
UPDATE products SET products_meta_description = CONCAT_WS('', SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_description, '.', 1), '.')
```

Sources

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws